# Convert from Iterator<T> to Iterator<U> where T is a subclass of U

Tags: java, generics

Given a class `T` which is a subclass of `U`, is it safe to cast `Iterator<T>` to `Iterator<U>`? And assuming that the cast be safe, are there more elegant (and warning-free) ways of doing it other than:

```
Iterator<T> it = <insert your Iterator<T> here...>;
Iterator<U> it2 = (Iterator<U>)(Iterator<? extends U>)it;
```

My reasoning why the cast is not dangerous is this:

1. `Iterator<?>` does not support inserting elements, so there is no danger of corrupting the underlying data structure by using `Iterator<U>` instead of `Iterator<T>`;
2. `Consumer<? super U>` is convertible to `Consumer<? super T>` but not vice versa. Hence, `Iterator<U>::forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super U> action)` will accept a subset of all actions eligible for the same method in `Iterator<T>` and, in particular, does not introduce a way of executing actions not supported by `Iterator<T>`;
3. `Iterator<U>::remove()` is equivalent to `Iterator<T>::remove()`;
4. `Iterator<U>::next()` returns a superclass of T;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, I don't see any reason it should be unsafe.

I believe that

```
Iterator<U> it2 = (Iterator) it;
```

should be sufficient to make the cast compile, but you would still have to suppress the warnings if you wanted it without a warning. Suppressing a warning is fine if you understand the reason for the warning and know it will not apply in this case.

Perhaps whatever code you are using that demands an `Iterator<U>` should be refactored to accept `Iterator<? extends U>` instead.

Comment: I have indeed refactored the code the way you suggest. It was a purely theoretical question which I thought might be of interest for the community.